# JavaScript convert txt to JSON, not able to get data in JSON, return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I first convert txt to JSON.

```css
const txt = JSON.stringify(`{
  ErrorList: [{ 80: 'Prepared' }],
  Reference: [
    {
      'Rule Name': 'Missing 3',
      'Rule ID': 1,
      'Rule Des': 'Did they provide News ?'
    },
    {
      'Rule Name': 'Missing Zip',
      'Rule ID': 2,
      'Rule Des': 'Is field ?'
    }
  ],
  'Hard Violation': [
    {
      Violation: 0,
      'Initial Servicer': 'BI',
      'Total Confirmed': 0,
      'Last Date': '05/16/2021'
    },
    {
      Violation: 0,
      'Initial Servicer': 'BI',
      'Total Confirmed': 3,
      'Last Date': '12/19/2019'
    }
  ]
}`);

const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
console.log(obj.Reference);
```

Then ,I tried to get some value of the JSON ,I tried to print the "Reference" inside it ,but it returns "undefined" ,any friend can help ?

Comment: You are stringifiying a string

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you for your reply ,I'm new to js ,can you please let me know what the correct way ?

Comment: You don't want those outer ` quotes. That's what Mr White meant; you're passing content that is already a JSON string to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Also note that the content of that string itself is valid JavaScript syntax, so you don't need to involve the JSON API at all if what you want is the object structure.

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much for you reply ,can you give a detailed correct answer ?

Comment: Why do you think you need JSON here at all? JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you just need to create an object, do it directly: `const obj = { ErrorList: [ { 80: "Prepared", /*...*/ } ] /*...*/ };`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your reply ,especially from  @ T.J. Crowder

The best way for me is create an object, do it directly:

```
const obj = { ErrorList: [ { 80: "Prepared", /*...*/ } ] /*...*/ };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
you have to do like this

const text = `{

    "ErrorList": [
        {
            "80": "Prepared"
        }
    ],
    "Reference": [
        {
            "Rule Name": "Missing 3",
            "Rule ID": 1,
            "Rule Des": "Did they provide News ?"
        },
        {
            "Rule Name": "Missing Zip",
            "Rule ID": 2,
            "Rule Des": "Is field ?"
        }
    ],
    "Hard Violation": [
        {
            "Violation": 0,
            "Initial Servicer": "BI",
            "Total Confirmed": 0,
            "Last Date": "05/16/2021"
        },
        {
            "Violation": 0,
            "Initial Servicer": "BI",
            "Total Confirmed": 3,
            "Last Date": "12/19/2019"
        }
    ]
}`;


// Parse the JSON string into a JavaScript object
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(text);


// Access and manipulate the object as needed

console.log(jsonO`enter code here`bj.ErrorList);
console.log(jsonObj.Reference);
console.log(jsonObj['Hard Violation']);
```

Comment: No, you don't have to involve the JSON API at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).